# Add selected Attribute for option using ternary operator in JSPX

Tags: ternary-operator, selected, jspx

I want to add a condition to add selected "attribute" if the condition passed.

```
<select id="b${count}_ddeligible" class="form-control input-md" name="b${count}_ddeligible">
  <option>Select</option>
  <option value="N" ${aspBenefit.eligibleBasp=="N" ? 'selected' : ''}>No </option>
  <option value="Y" ${aspBenefit.eligibleBasp=="Y" ? 'selected' : ''}>Yes </option>
</select>
```

But I'm getting below error.

> Element type "option" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

Appreciate for any help !